# Properly seekToBeginning() all consumers in a group

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, spring-kafka

I have a goal to seek all consumers in a consumer group to the beginning of each partition. I use spring-kafka and tried to use the `ConsumerSeekAware` interface in the way:

```
override fun onPartitionsAssigned(assignments: MutableMap<TopicPartition, Long>?, callback: ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback?) {
  logger.info { "on partitions assigned" }
  assignments?.forEach { topic, _ -> callback?.seekToBeginning(topic.topic(), topic.partition()) }
}
```

Now, for only one consumer in a group it works, but what if I want to seek to begin more than one consumer? I tried it and it ended up in an infinite rebalancing of partitions. What do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up in making use of other methods of `ConsumerSeekAware`, namely `registerSeekCallback()`.
After calling `onPartitionsAssigned` I save current partitions as a member in the listener. The same after calling `registerSeekCallback` I save the callback in the instance.

Then I can do on demand call `consumeFromBeginning` for each consumer (through REST, or after start) :

```
class EventConsumer : ConsumerSeekAware {

    private lateinit var assignedTopicPartitions: List<TopicPartition>
    private lateinit var consumerSeekCallback: ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback

    fun consumeFromBeginning() {
        assignedTopicPartitions.forEach { topicPartition ->
            consumerSeekCallback.seekToBeginning(topicPartition.topic(), topicPartition.partition())}
    }

    override fun onPartitionsAssigned(assignments: MutableMap<TopicPartition, Long>?, callback: ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback?) {
        logger.debug { "on partitions assigned" }
        this.assignedTopicPartitions = assignments?.map { it.key } ?: error("no assignments found")
    }

    override fun registerSeekCallback(callback: ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback?) {
        logger.debug { "registerSeekCallback" }
        this.consumerSeekCallback = callback ?: error("seek callback not found")
    }

    override fun onIdleContainer(assignments: MutableMap<TopicPartition, Long>?, callback: ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback?) {}
}
```